# Web server and MySQL server on different machines, causing latency on websites

Tags: mysql, apache, centos, virtualization

I am currently running a virtualized environment for my web and db server.  When I access the web server or the MySQL server individually, they are both fast.  I also have websites running on the web server that do not require the db server and those all load quickly.  However, when I access my hosted website that requires the web server to call from the db server, there is about a 5-7 second latency for every page load.  This has been confirmed with both a very simple site and with a Word Press setup as well.  Here is the config:

Web server - CentOS 6.5, Apache 2.2.15

DB server - CentOS 6.5, MySQL 5.1.73

My question is, are the servers continuously authenticating with one another (and thus causing latency) on every single db call?  If that is the case, does anyone know how to permanently authenticate between the two?

I might be way off on this assumption and authentication could have nothing to do with it.  I am completely open to any and all ideas at this point.  Thank you very much.

V/R,

Tony

Comment: You could do a tracert to the db server ip, from the web server....

Comment: How do you connect to the database? Where are the servers with relation to one another?

Comment: Check if the MySQL server can resolve the IP of the web server (`nslookup <webserver_ip>`), if it can't or it's too slow try to add the webserver's IP with a host in the DB server's `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems to be a network issue.
and obviously the db-server will need authentication every time there is a hit.